# Using functions with orientdb select query with edge filter

Tags: orientdb

Schema

> Customer -> (Edge)Ownes -> Vehicle {vehicle_number}

tried to query the customer record who "Ownes" a vehicle by its number like below and it worked. (both 'in' and 'contains' worked fine)

```
select from Customer where "KL-01-B-8898" in  out("Ownes").vehicle_number
```

I want to do the same query but using a case insensitive search, like below, but returned '0' records

```
select from Customer where "kl-01-b-8898" in  out("Ownes").vehicle_number.toLowerCase()
```

I changed the query like below and it returned the rows. Is it possible to use functions like 'toLowerCase' in the queries like above, with out sub select ?

```
select from Customer where @rid in (select in("Ownes").@rid from Vehicle  where vehicle_number.toLowerCase() ="kl-01-b-8898")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
select from Customer 
let $a= ( select number.toUpperCase() from (select out("Ownes").vehicle_number as number from $parent.$current unwind number))
where "KL-01-B-8898" in first($a).number
```

This doesn't work:

```
select from Customer where "kl-01-b-8898" in out("Ownes").vehicle_number.toLowerCase()
```

because

```
out("Ownes").vehicle_number
```

return a list of String

This works:

```
select from Customer where @rid in (select in("Ownes").@rid from Vehicle  where vehicle_number.toLowerCase() ="kl-01-b-8898")
```

because vehicle_number is a String

See the documentation: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Methods.html#bundled-methods